# Why is For loop on Regex Matches slow?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, regex

I have the following code:

```
        string pattern = @"(?:\S+\s){1,6}\S*" + search + @"\S*(?:\s\S+){1,6}";
        String dbContents = row[2].ToString();
        var matches = Regex.Matches(dbContents, pattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Compiled);
        for (int i = 0; i < matches.Count; i++)
        {
            if (i == 3)
                break;

            Contents += String.Format("... {0} ...", matches[i].Value);
        }
```

What I'm trying to accomplish is to get one to six words before the search term and 1-6 words after the search term. When executing the code the performance hit on the for loop "matches.Count". With very large strings, its taking upwards of a min to execute. I'm confused on why and what to do to fix the issue.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In order to find the count, that has to find *all* the matches in order to count them. Given that you're going to stop after three anyway, that seems a little pointless.

Use `MatchCollection`'s lazy evaluation in combination with the [`Take`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb503062.aspx) method from LINQ to only take the first three matches. Usually it's a good idea to use `StringBuilder` rather than string concatenation in a loop, too:

```
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(...);
foreach (var match in matches.Cast<Match>().Take(3))
{
    builder.AppendFormat("... {0} ...", matches[i].Value);
}
```

(The `StringBuilder` change probably isn't going to make much difference here, but it's a good habit to get into. The [`Cast`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb341406.aspx) method is required because `Enumerable.Take` only works on the generic `IEnumerable<T>` type.)

Comment: Thank you! Late night of bashing my head on the wall. That has drastically increased performance. I'm getting around 5sec load times compared to 58.67sec

Answer (score 3):

From MSDN:

> The `Matches` method uses lazy evaluation to populate the returned
>   MatchCollection object. Accessing members of this collection such as
>   MatchCollection.Count and MatchCollection.CopyTo causes the collection
>   to be populated immediately. To take advantage of lazy evaluation, you
>   should iterate the collection by using a construct such as `foreach` in
>   C#

Bottom line: change your code to use `foreach`.

Answer (score 3):

Another way to do this is to call `Match` and then `NextMatch`, like this:

```
    var match = Regex.Match(dbContents, pattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Compiled);
    for (int i = 0; i < 3 && match.Success; i++)
    {
        Contents += String.Format("... {0} ...", matches[i].Value);
        match = match.NextMatch();
    }
```

Comment: I think you mean `Regex.Match` not `Regex.Matches` in the first line?